# SQL server Import and Export Wizard conversion VS Alter Command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Just attempted to import a `.xls` file into database by using `SQL server Import and Export Wizard`, for some of the fields in `.xls` file, there exists `whitespace` value. Those fields should be either `DATE` or `MONEY` type in the target table.

I tried to `Edit Mapping` for those columns, and it gave the error message saying cannot convert those field value for me because of `potential data loss`.

Here comes my confusing part, I ignore the data type on `Import and Export Wizard` level, just leave them as original `nvarchar`, and try to `ALTER COLUMN` such as `Alter table.. Alter column col1 DATE`, and it succeeded. 
Why those fields would be converted without any issue (actually those blank values were converted either to `1900/01/01` for `DATE` column and `0.00` for `MONEY` column, even the `Import and Export Wizard` gives me these result, I can accept.) To be precisely of what I am confused is why the `ALTER` command did not throw the error for `potential data loss` and could convert blank value to the initial value of other types?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe `nvarchar` will accept pretty much anything.  IT is definitely more forgiving than most data types.  Yeah, for sure, excel will take whatever you give it, and let you get away with all kinds of sloppiness.  As you've discovered, when you go from the Excel world into the database world, you need to be much more disciplined in what kinds of data types you use.